# Basic Express Routes puzzle

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got stuck in Mozilla js tutorial and need help. Here are excerpts from  3 files:

a)

the 2 pieces from app.js file show where to find Router handlers and then where to present them (my guess)

```
    //app.js
    //the following 3 vars do sit in routes folder, code copy-pasted var 3 my addition
    var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
    var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

    var coolRouter = require('./routes/cool');

    var app = express();

    ....

    //the following 2 'use' work just fine, the third sends err 404, 'not found'
    app.use('/', indexRouter);
    app.use('/users', usersRouter);

    app.use('/users/cool', coolRouter);
```

b) part of the users.js sitting in routes folder:

```
    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.send('respond with a resource');
    });
```

c) part of the cool.js copied from the previous and sitting in routes folder:

```
    /* GET cool text. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.send('you are cool, kid!');
    });
```

I'd like to get it why it does not work.

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: Yea like what’s not working ?  Be clear with your question __ am down voting this till you edit your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot reach **/users/cool** is that your request is being cathed by the **/users** endpoint.
In order for your code to work as you intend it to do, you will have to place your routes like this:

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users/cool', coolRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

With the **/users/cool** endpoint before the **/users** endpoint. That way, the request to **/users/cool** will not be catched by another endpoint.

Comment: yes! it works now! I would never guess it I swear! I googled and googled and goolged it and not a hint in any of tutorials.

Comment: @sehrguey Please mark this as an solution if it solved the problem :)